# Checkbox filter for range in ng-repeat with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-filter

I have an array that looks like this:

```
[
    {
    'age':5
    },

    {
    'age':12
    },

    {
    'age':51
    },
]
```

I display the data using an ng-repeat list and I wish to be able to filter through the list using severl checkboxes with integer comparision, for example, `age = 5 < 0` and `age = 14 < 5`.

I've used checkbox filters before, but right now I can't seem to figure out a way to deal with this..

I've tried the following but no luck:

```
.filter('five', function () {
  return function (input, age) {

    var output = [];

    if (isNaN(age)) {
        output = input;
    }

    else {
        angular.forEach(input, function (item) {
            if (item.age < 5) {
                output.push(item)
            }
        });
    }
    return output;
  }
})
```

In combination with:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="five" ng-model="fivemodel" ng-change="fivemodel = fivemodel ? true : undefined">
    <label for="five="> <5 yo </label>

<div ng-repeat="item in items | five"></div>
```

Any tips?

### EDIT

See [Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/Tjx9BWf3ZCAXB9iD57Kr?p=preview) for reference.

Comment: put your code on codepen or jsfiddlw. So that we can run and check.

Comment: your ng-model, filter, id, everything is `five`. It could help to rename few things first

Comment: Done and done! I hope it helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See working example [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/ZtSipKGOuspKZfbZuBW0?p=preview)

Check on checkbox will filter result having age <=5; and uncheck will show all results

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="test">

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.6.6" data-semver="1.6.6" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.6/angular.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>

  </head>

  <body ng-controller="wop">
    <input type="checkbox" id="five" ng-model="fiveFilter" >
    <label for="five="> 5 yo </label>

<div ng-repeat="item in data |five:fiveFilter">{{item.age}}</div>
  </body>

</html>
<script>
    // Code goes here

angular.module('test',[])

.controller('wop',['$scope', function($scope){

    // DEFINE DATE DEFAULTS
$scope.data = [
    {
    'age':5
    },

    {
    'age':12
    },

    {
    'age':51
    },
];



}])

.filter('five', function () {
  return function ( items,filter) {
      if(filter)return items.filter(x=>x.age<=5);
      else return items;
  }
})
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you need an age filter to filter the array. Not sure how a checkbox can help you to achieve this. I added 2 text boxes instead of checkbox and try to do the same. Here is the html code

```
 <label>Age From: </label>
<input type="text" ng-model="fromAge">
<label>Age To: </label>
<input type="text" ng-model="toAge">

<ul ng-repeat="item in data | filter: filterAge">
  <li>
    {{item.age}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

Here is the js code

```
 $scope.filterAge = function(obj) {

if ((!$scope.fromAge || $scope.fromAge === 0) 
&& (!$scope.toAge || $scope.toAge === 0)) {
  return true;
}

return obj.age >= ($scope.fromAge ? $scope.fromAge : 0) && 
obj.age <= ($scope.toAge ? $scope.toAge : 0);

}
```

[Link to jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e2mwk6r8/1/)